# Fit Viewport Black Bars

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm currently developing a game where you have to avoid Asteroids. To make the Game look same on every device I use the FitViewport. Unfortunately I somehow get White Bars on the top and on the Bottom instead of Black ones. My Game Background is also white, so it looks a bit weird.

GameScreen:

```
     @Override
     public void create() 
     {
        float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(MyGdxGame.WIDTH * aspectRatio, MyGdxGame.HEIGHT, cam);
        [...]
     }


     @Override
     public void render(SpriteBatch batch) 
     {
        cam.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.begin();
        em.render(batch); //render Ship and Asteroids
        [...]
     }


     @Override
     public void resize(int width, int height) 
     {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        cam.position.set(MyGdxGame.WIDTH / 2, MyGdxGame.HEIGHT /2, 0);
     }
```

[image]

I dragged the Ship into the white Bar.

Comment: Try adding these lines before `cam.update()`, if you haven't already:
`Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f)`
`Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`

Comment: Unfortunately the hole background is black with these two lines. I think i have to use a White Texture as Background if i want to create the effect. -Thanks-

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX provides viewports as a more convenient way of dealing with different aspect ratios. You don't have to multiply MyGdxGame.WIDTH with aspectRatio. Just initialize it with MyGdxGame.WIDTH and MyGdxGame.HEIGHT.

Also, in resize function, you can change the cam position using viewport values (instead of using constants):

```
cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some issues in your code. for best practice while handling with the different screen ratio just try with the fill viewPort. Here is simply editing your code with the fill viewport . Just try it once.

```
         @Override
         public void create() 
         {
            float aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight();


            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            camera.update();
            //1280 is the screen width and 800 is screen height
            camera.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 800);
            viewPort = new FillViewport(1280, 800, camera);

         }


         @Override
         public void render(SpriteBatch batch) 
         {

            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            batch.begin();
            em.render(batch); //render Ship and Asteroids
            [...]
         }


         @Override
         public void resize(int width, int height) 
         {
           viewPort.update(width, height);
         }

 just try with the above code . it will definitely work
```